# Ethernet FCS when capturing wth Wireshark under Linux

Tags: linux, ethernet, wireshark

Is there some way to get the Frame Check Sequence (FCS) from an ethernet frame when using Wireshark to capture packets under Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i receive the wrong Ethernet frames and disable the CRC/FCS calcul?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101650/how-can-i-receive-the-wrong-ethernet-frames-and-disable-the-crc-fcs-calcul)

Comment: The answers here say this can't be done, but this later question and answer says how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101650/how-can-i-receive-the-wrong-ethernet-frames-and-disable-the-crc-fcs-calcul

Answer (score 2):

The FCS is generated by the sender's ethernet device and decoded by the recipients ethernet device.  If the FCS is correct, the payload is passed up to higher layers.  If it's not, then the potential frame is discarded.

Because it's added for the exclusive use of the ethernet layer, there's no reason to pass the data up to the operating system.  There's no reason for the hardware to include additional capabilities of moving that data out of the card.  All modern ethernet devices do onboard FCS processing (and often much more).  The only exception would be devices intended to analyze ethernet performance and function.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ethernet](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Ethernet) wiki page on [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) states:

> Most Ethernet interfaces also either don't supply the FCS to Wireshark or other applications

so I assume the answer is a *no*.